# Android application permission settings

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

My internal android application worked fine on Samsung Tab S2 and it automatically got permissions to access 'storage' and 'location' of the device. But, when I am installing the application on newer Samsung Galaxy Tab S7, I have to manually provide permission for the app in settings. By default it is set to "No permissions allowed" How cam I automate this.
AndroidManifest.xml has following settings

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: @Michael thanks that explains why it was working on older version which had android 5.2 but on these running Android 9

Comment: decrease target version, then it wont

Answer (score 0):

Android permissions went through a radical change after android `M` was released. before that, developers can simply jam all the permissions in the `AndroidManifesto` file, and before the user installs the app, he/she has to approve all the permissions to run the app.

However, things are different now. Android expects that these permissions will be granted at rather runtime, i.e. when a feature that needs that permission is executed, it first requests for that permission, and based on user's reply handle that. If permission is granted, then good. If not, then simply display a message maybe stating that this feature will not work in the absence of that permission. In which case, because the user has already declined the permission, he/she now has to go to the settings to enable the previously declined permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant permission from the user. You can use it inside **Fragment**:

> Java:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            REQUEST_LOCATION);
} else {
    Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED");
}
```

> Kotlin:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(getActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_LOCATION)
    } else {
        Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED")
    }
```

and inside **Activity**:

> Java:

```
int checkPermission= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
if (checkPermission!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)getContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
}
else {
    Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED")
}
```

> Kotlin:

```
    val checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getContext() as Activity, arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), REQUEST_LOCATION)
}
else
{
  Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED")
}
```